# How to convert Dataset to a Scala Iterable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to convert a org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset to a scala.collection.Iterable?  It seems like this should be simple enough.

Answer (score 7):

You can do `myDataset.collect` or `myDataset.collectAsList`.

But then it will no longer be distributed. If you want to be able to spread your computations out on multiple machines you need to use one of the distributed datastructures such as RDD, Dataframe or Dataset.

You can also use `toLocalIterator` if you just need to iterate the contents on the driver as it has the advantage of only loading one partition at a time, instead of the entire dataset, into memory. `Iterator` is not an `Iterable` (although it is a `Traverable`) but depending on what you are doing it may be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
def toLocalIterable[T](dataset: Dataset[T]): Iterable[T] = new Iterable[T] {     
  def iterator = scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIterator(dataset.toLocalIterator)
}
```

The conversion via `JavaConverters.asScalaIterator` is necessary because the `toLocalIterator` method of `Dataset` returns a `java.util.Iterator` instead of a `scala.collection.Iterator` (which is what the `toLocalIterator` on `RDD` returns.) I suspect this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.11 you can do the following:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

dataset.toLocalIterator.asScala.toIterable
```

Comment: Does keep things lazy, or does it materialize full collections?